# Image processing extension for php

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, gmagick

I am looking for an image processing extension for PHP. I know about gd but it does not have all the features I need. I want to crop, resize, compress images, generate images on the fly, create thumbnails of images, etc.

I would like to know which extensions are available and also how to install them. I know about imagemagick and gmagick; imagemagick is more resource hungry than gmagick but when I tried to use gmagick it is not working properly. Maybe I have not installed it correctly. If anyone knows how to install gmagick on Windows Vista please let me know.

If there are better extensions for image processing in PHP please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the gd library documentation again. It does allow for image creation, see  http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php and more specifically, the example on image creation http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php.

Comment: agree. gd can do everything you just mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

To create thumbnails you can use the executable named 'FFMPEG' which open source and used by youtube too.

For cropping and resizing you donot need a third party I guess.

To compress means ? Well you can zip the image by using pre loaded libraries in PHP.

GIF Images provideds LZW compression. You can convert image to GIF format also. This may result in loss of color definition if the source image file is some JPEG file especially.

:)

Comment: to compress means i need to reduce the file size before storing it to database user upload images of any dimensions and of any any size i need to convert this images in to 720px X 400px size to display for images which are more than 1024 X 980 i  know about gmagick but i dont know how to install it

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this PHP library.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Cheers!

Prasad.

Comment: imagemagick is very resource intensive and slow as per my research on imagemagick and gmagick